# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket when using a connection pool?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

When I connect to a database using a connection pool I get this exception.

So then I tried connecting to the database using the basic Class.forName(); and DriverManager method I was able to do so..  why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem may arise wherever a connection pool is involved. The reason for this is as follows.

**The Reason:**

- Say in your application you have configured a connection pool. And you ask for a 5 connection objects.
- Your connection pool is usually handled by a Container like Tomcat, Spring, or CQ5(in my case)
- Now you leave your application idle for some time, but the container and the connection pool is still active
- **And now the magic trick**, the Database server restarts as per schedule.
- **This makes the alive/active connection objects inside your application servers's connection Pool BROKEN**
- So you come in the next moment and suddenly you get these errors when it was working fine some time ago.

**The Solution:**

- You can reset the connection pool- This is the best option. This would delete the current broken Connections residing in the pool and forcefully create a new Connection Pool with new connection objects inside them.
- You can restart the application server. Not recommended.(You can't keep restarting application servers in Production)

Reference [Link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201207.mbox/%3C1342876267.25585.28.camel@cat%3E)